# How can I best improve the execution time of a bicubic interpolation algorithm?

Tags: c++, performance, image-processing, interpolation, bicubic

I'm developing some image processing software in C++ on Intel which has to run a bicubic interpolation algorithm on small (about 1kpx) images over and over again. This takes a lot of time, and I'm aiming to speed it up. What I have now is a basic implementation based on the literature, a somewhat-improved (with regard to speed) version which doesn't do matrix multiplication, but rather uses pre-calculated formulas for parts of the interpolating polynomial and last, a fixed-point version of the matrix-multiplying code (works slower actually). I also have an external library with an optimized implementation, but it's still too slow for my needs. What I was considering next is:

- vectorization using MMX/SSE stream processing, on both the floating and fixed-point versions
- doing the interpolation in the Fourier domain using convolution
- shifting the work onto a GPU using OpenCL or similar

Which of these approaches could yield greatest performance gains? Could you suggest another? Thanks.

Comment: How slow we talking about?  Slow because you perform a relatively fast operation many times or because it's a lot slower than you'd expect?

Comment: I suppose it's relatively fast, but I need to do it A LOT of times. The external library pulls it of in about 27us (with SSE), my best implementation pulls about 50us.

Comment: If you use the GPU, what do you do with the output of the algorithm, will you need to go back to main memory, that in itself could be a bottleneck?

Comment: What is this "external library" you are referring to? Also is 1k px image a 100x10 or a 1000x1000?

Comment: The library I use is OpenCV. As for the size of the image, I meant a 1000px total. They are usually square, that is 32x32 in size.

Comment: are you interpolating to a regular grid, 32x32 -> n x n ? or how ?

Comment: I am interpolating from non-regular coordinates in a larger (usually 1024x768) image into a regular 32x32 image. The non-regular coordinates are obtained from a formula creating a deformation map (mapping each of the regular 32x32 points into non-regular locations in the original image, which need to be interpolated). Does this clear it up? I'm confused. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think GPU is the way to go.  It's probably the most natural task for this type of hardware.  I would start by looking into [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html) or [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/).  Older techniques like simple DirectX/OpenGL  pixel/fragment shaders should work just fine as well.

Some links I found, maybe they could help you:

- [Efficient GPU-Based Texture Interpolation using Uniform B-Splines](http://www.mate.tue.nl/mate/pdfs/10318.pdf)
- [CUDA Cubic B-Spline Interpolation (CI)](http://www.dannyruijters.nl/cubicinterpolation/)
- [Fast Third-Order Texture Filtering](http://http.download.nvidia.com/developer/SDK/Individual_Samples/DEMOS/OpenGL/src/fast_third_order/docs/Gems2_ch20_SDK.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

There's the [Intel IPP libraries](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp-kb-home/), which use SIMD internally for faster processing.  The Intel IPP also uses OpenMP, if configured, you can gain benefit of relatively easy multiprocessing.

These libraries do support bicubic interpolation and are payware (you buy a development license but redistribs are free).

Comment: +1: You now get an IPP license when you buy the Intel ICC compiler (and there are no runtime licensing issues). ICC alone should give some performance improvement over gcc or Visual Studio, and IPP would definitely be the first thing to try before writing custom SIMD code.

Comment: @Paul R, thanks for the great tip, I'll have a serious look at this compiler.

Comment: @ChrisO I see that IPP has support for cubic interpolation but not bicubic. Are they considered the same?

Comment: @JoaoMilasch Yes, I believe "bicubic" and "cubic" are the same concept, if you look at Fig. B-2 in ippiman.pdf, you can see the use of the cubic polynomials in two dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with going the GPU route.  If your convolution kernel is too fast, you're going to end up being IO bound.  You won't know for sure which is the fastest unless you implement both.

GPU Gems 2 has a chapter on [Fast Third-Order Texture Filtering](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter20.html) which should be a good starting point for your GPU solution.

A combination of [Intel Threading Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) and SSE instructions would make a decent CPU solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer for bicubic, but maybe an alternative:
if I understand you, you have 32 x 32 xy, 1024 x 768 image, and want interpolated `image[xy]`.
Just rounding xy, `image[ int( xy )]`, would be too grainy.
But wait — you could make a smoothed double image 2k x 1.5k, once, and take
`image2[ int( 2*xy )]`: less grainy, very fast. Or similarly,
`image4[ int( 4*xy )]` in a smoothed 4k x 3k image.
How well this works depends on ...

Comment: Actually, this is the other way around; I have an 1024x768 image, and I want to create an interpolated 32x32 xy based on non-evenly distributed data points from "image".

Comment: yes, image[xy] is 32x32 from image.  Consider 1d, 32 values at x0 .. x31 from 1k points: if you want to interpolate many different xy from one image (is that your case ?), make a smooth blowup of the image once, to 2k or 4k, and take 32 values from xy rounded to integers. These sample the original image at half / quarter pixels, fast.